# where do i find dbms_scheduler in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have created a `dbms_scheduler` job in sql developer, but in PL/SQL Developer i cannot see this job. I get see only the `dbms_job`.

Have some way to see the `dbms_scheduler` job in UI in PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: Have a look under `Jobs` node.

Comment: where does stay the node on the PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: Don't you use PL/SQL Developer from Allround automations ? In the bottom part of the `Objects` window, you'll see that(`Jobs` node) after `Programs`, before `Job classes` node.

Comment: i commonly use SQL Developer, but i need to find  that in PL/SQL. Could you send me a print?

Comment: well, perhaps [this](https://imgur.com/l2vjGcM) might help.

Comment: as you can see, this is not available to me: https://imgur.com/a/CpeVPdh

Comment: No, the 11th one, just one rank over `Queues`

Comment: yes,but here i can see only the dbms_job, i need to see also the dbms_scheduler jobs

Comment: consider selecting scheduler views like `user_scheduler_jobs`, `user_scheduler_running_jobs` and `user_scheduler_job_run_details` in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find `DBMS_SCHEDULER` jobs in the Jobs folder in recent versions of PL/SQL Developer. In older versions you'll have to run `select * from all_scheduler_jobs;`

Your old version was probably created before DBMS_SCHEDULER existed, so your Jobs folder only reads from `ALL_JOBS`. Newer versions have two folders, DBMS_Jobs that reads from `ALL_JOBS`, and Jobs that reads from `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS`. When you find your scheduler job you can right-click on it and either view or edit the properties.

For example, if I create this job:

```
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job
    (
        job_name   => 'TEST_JOB',
        job_type   => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action => 'begin null; end;',
        auto_drop  => false);
end;
/
```

I see these results in the Object window:

[image]